# Opening only a part of AWS-hosted web API to public

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a web API application running in AWS. Access to it is restricted to certain IP addresses using security groups.
I need to make available to public only one specific URL of that application. At the first glance API Gateway can do the job. However, I cannot find any settings which allow traffic coming from API Gateway.
Am I looking in the right direction?

Comment: I want to explore the part of the Web App for specific hostnames only. Searching for days but still did not get a foolproof solution.  Please help soon.